# Using SPI to manipulate Flash Memory (Code in C)

Tags: microcontroller, c, spi, flash, flash-memories

for a couple of days i have been trying to write a C code that writes to a flash memory via SPI. I already have a code that writes characters into flash. Now i wanted to expand on it and write integer into flash. The problem is that it seems like i can't fully erase the flash memory array. Only the lower 8 bit are erased which is fine for characters but for integer it's a problem.

Here is what i am using:

An open-source platform that uses the RISC-V ISA: https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulpissimo

This is not exactly the SDK i am using, but all the relevant functions are the same: https://greenwaves-technologies.com/manuals/BUILD/PULP-OS/html/index.html

This flash memory: https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/cypress-semiconductor-corp/cypress-semiconductor-corp-download-s25fs128s256s

I am using a HDL simulation environment by Mentor Graphics for simulation.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rt/rt_api.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32

typedef struct {
    rt_spim_t *device;
    int *tx_buffer;
    int *rx_buffer;
} spi_flash_t;

rt_spim_conf_t* spi_flash_init_cfg(){
  rt_spim_conf_t *conf = malloc(sizeof(rt_spim_conf_t));
  rt_spim_conf_init(conf);
  conf->max_baudrate = 1000000;
  conf->id = 0;
  conf->cs = 0;
  conf->phase = 1;
  conf->polarity = 1;
  conf->big_endian = 1;
  conf->wordsize = RT_SPIM_WORDSIZE_32;
  return conf;
}

spi_flash_t* spi_flash_open(rt_spim_conf_t *conf) {
  rt_spim_t *device = rt_spim_open(NULL, conf, NULL);
  spi_flash_t *flash = malloc(sizeof(spi_flash_t));
  flash->device = device;
  flash->tx_buffer = rt_alloc(RT_ALLOC_PERIPH, BUFFER_SIZE);
  flash->rx_buffer = rt_alloc(RT_ALLOC_PERIPH, BUFFER_SIZE);
  return flash;
}

void spi_flash_write_enable(spi_flash_t *flash){
  flash->tx_buffer[0] = 0x06;
  rt_spim_send(flash->device, flash->tx_buffer, 8, RT_SPIM_CS_AUTO, NULL);
}

void spi_flash_close(spi_flash_t *flash){
  rt_spim_close(flash->device, NULL);
}

char spi_flash_read_sr1(spi_flash_t *flash){
  flash->tx_buffer[0] = 0x05;
  rt_spim_send(flash->device, flash->tx_buffer, 8, RT_SPIM_CS_KEEP, NULL);
  rt_spim_receive(flash->device, flash->rx_buffer, 8, RT_SPIM_CS_AUTO, NULL);
  return flash->rx_buffer[0];
}

char spi_flash_read_sr2(spi_flash_t *flash){
  flash->tx_buffer[0] = 0x07;
  rt_spim_send(flash->device, flash->tx_buffer, 8, RT_SPIM_CS_KEEP, NULL);
  rt_spim_receive(flash->device, flash->rx_buffer, 8, RT_SPIM_CS_AUTO, NULL);
  return flash->rx_buffer[0];
}

void spi_flash_wait_sr1(spi_flash_t *flash){
  while(spi_flash_read_sr1(flash) & 0x1){
  }
}

void spi_flash_wait_sr2(spi_flash_t *flash){
  while(spi_flash_read_sr2(flash) & 0x1){
  }
}

void spi_flash_bulk_erase(spi_flash_t *flash){
  flash->tx_buffer[0] = 0x60;
  rt_spim_send(flash->device, flash->tx_buffer, 32, RT_SPIM_CS_NONE, NULL);
}

void spi_flash_write_test(spi_flash_t *flash, int* data){
  flash->tx_buffer[0] = 0x02;
  rt_spim_send(flash->device, flash->tx_buffer, 32, RT_SPIM_CS_KEEP, NULL);
  flash->tx_buffer[0] = data[0];
  flash->tx_buffer[1] = data[1];
  flash->tx_buffer[2] = data[2];
  flash->tx_buffer[3] = data[3];
  rt_spim_send(flash->device, flash->tx_buffer, (32*4), RT_SPIM_CS_AUTO, NULL);
}

int main()
{

  int data[] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333};

  rt_spim_conf_t *config = spi_flash_init_cfg();
  spi_flash_t *flash = spi_flash_open(config);

  spi_flash_write_enable(flash);
  spi_flash_bulk_erase(flash);
  spi_flash_wait_sr2(flash);

  spi_flash_write_enable(flash);
  spi_flash_write_test(flash, data);
  spi_flash_wait_sr1(flash);

  spi_flash_close(flash);

  return 0;
}
```

There is probably something super obvious and i'm too blind to see it, but i can't write integer into the flash memory. As i said it seems like the bulk erase only erases the lower 8 bit of every entry in the memory. After executing this code my flash memory looks like this:

000000ef

000000be

000000ad

000000de

00000011

00000011

00000011

00000011

00000022

00000022

00000022

00000022

00000033

00000033

00000033

00000033

000000ff

000000ff

000000ff

( ... )

I thought that maybe block protection was the reason for this, but turning it off (which i might have failed to do so) and reading the register to check if block protection is enabled (which i might have also failed to do correctly) both didn't help.

This is the first time i'm trying to do something like this and i am really struggling to find the mistake.
I know this is quite a lot and very specific, but i would greatly appreciate any input that might help me solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Flash memory is block device. This means that minimal erasable unit is block. Block consists of several pages. Page is a minimal writable unit. It is impossible that erase command clear only lower bits of each entry.
How you print data which is read from flash?

Comment: RT_SPIM_CS_NONE - Don't do anything with the chip select. You use this for erase bulk. But if you check datasheet p.114 figure 92, chip select must be asserted during bulk erase.